# Adding data- attribute to an ASP MVC @Html.RouteLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I would like to use a javascript library that hits the data- attribute in the link i have created.

```
@model IEnumerable<string>


@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(
      link,
      new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category = link, page = 1 },
      new
      {
          @class = link == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "selected" : null, 
          id= link.Replace(" ","")
      }
    )
}
```

I am able to add a class and a id but when i try to add **data-filter** it returns and error

```
 @class = link == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "selected" : null, 
      data-filter = link.Replace(" ","")
```

> Invalid annonymous type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@class = link == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "selected" : null, 
  data_filter = link.Replace(" ","")
```

As D.R. has pointed out, MVC has the option of turning underscores in dashes.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use dashes in property names. The solution is to use underscores instead: `data_filter = ...`. ASP.NET MVC automatically converts the underscore to a dash afterwards.